# How to Compile and Bulid a single file in maven project

Tags: eclipse, maven, jsf, build

I am doing maven web project in JSf - Richfaces. I have been using "maven clean install" for clearing and build the project to create a war file. It is tedious work to build an entire project for a changes in a single file.

My Question is,

1. Is there any possibility to build a single java file instead of entire project.
2. Can we create a short cut or icon in eclipse to build the current project 
   (ie)"mvn clean install" to create  war file

Comment: Are you working inside a IDE like Eclipse?

Answer (score -1):

Maven uses incremental compilation i.e. it compiles only classes that changed on disk since the last build.

you can modify your pom.xml , so that "clean, install , deploy" happens automatically. Below is the code that you can append after customizing necessary fields

```
<build>
<plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>7.6.Final</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>deploy</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```